# How to export PHAsset video by UIActivityViewController in iOS

Tags: ios

I tried to export `PHAsset` Video by `UIActivityViewController` in iOS.
It worked fine when PHAsset was image. The problem was when `PHAsset` was video.
I had the following code to export `PHAsset` video, but nothing was attached.

```
    var asset = getCurrentAsset() as PHAsset?

    if asset == nil {
        return
    }

    if asset?.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.Video {

        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(asset, options: nil) { (avAsset:AVAsset!, audioMix:AVAudioMix!, info:[NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in
            var videoURL = avAsset as AVURLAsset
            var activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [videoURL], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityVC.completionHandler = {(str: String!, value: Bool) -> Void in
            }
            self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Please help me how to export `PHAsset` video.

Answer (score 3):

I have wasted a lot of time to do that.

Finally I resolved it by saving the video to document directory, and using the file url from document directory.

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestExportSessionForVideo: self.videosAssets[index] options:nil exportPreset:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough resultHandler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession, NSDictionary *info) {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* videoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempSelvi.MOV"];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error;
    if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:videoPath]) {
        BOOL success = [manager removeItemAtPath:videoPath error:&error];
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Already exist. Removed!");
        }
    }

    NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    NSLog(@"Final path %@",outputURL);
    exportSession.outputFileType=AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exportSession.outputURL=outputURL;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"failed");
        } else if(exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted){
            NSLog(@"completed!");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:outputURL, nil];

                UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
                activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
                    NSError *error;
                    if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:videoPath]) {
                        BOOL success = [manager removeItemAtPath:videoPath error:&error];
                        if (success) {
                            NSLog(@"Successfully removed temp video!");
                        }
                    }
                    [weakSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                };
                [weakSelf presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            });     
        }
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attach the `AVURLAsset` itself, instead you should specify its `URL` of the `AVURLAsset` as the activityItems.

So, use `avAsset.URL` should work, `avAsset` is an instance object of type `AVURLAsset`.

**Edit**

```
let theAsset = avAsset as AVURLAsset
let videoURL = theAsset.URL
var activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [videoURL], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,Gabbler. I changed AVURLAsset to AVURLAsset.URL, but it doesn't still work. Can you please guide me in detail?

Comment: When I clicked "Save Video" option in UIActivityViewController, it worked. The problem appeared with "Mail" option. When I clicked "Mail" option, nothing was attached. Can you please guide me how to do it? Thank you

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: You have to set up your mail account in iPhone.

Comment: Yes. I know. The New Message Dialog is shown by UIActivityController, but the video is not attached in the body. If I send it to another mail, there isn't also that video. As I said before, it works perfectly for image.

Comment: Test with other email account, like gmail. If you attach a mov file in your resource bundle, it works.

Comment: Oops! The video isn't in resource bundle. It comes from camera roll.

Comment: I don't really know why the video isn't attached in the email. but if you use UIImagePickerController, and let user choose which video to share, then it is showed in the email. I guess this makes more sense, we can't programmatically inspect the local videos and attach one secretly, we better make user choose which one to attach.