# Sharing Video PHAsset via UIActivityController

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiactivityviewcontroller, phasset

I am trying to share video **PHAsset** via **UIActivityController** using requestAVAsset. This works with Messaging, but not with AirDrop, indicating as 'Failed'.

```
PHCachingImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler:
    { (givenAsset, audioMix, info) in

        let videoAsset = givenAsset as! AVURLAsset
        let videoURL = videoAsset.url

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
                activityItems: [videoURL],
                applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll]

            if let popoverPresentationController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = (sender)
            }

            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
})
```

This seems to properly put up **UIActivityController** and only work with certain activities:

- **Messaging** - ✔️Works, properly exports video.
- **AirDrop** - ✖️Shows "Failed"
- **Dropbox** - ✖️Puts up the proper Dropbox View, yet says "Unknown error occurred"

---

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've run into similarly odd behavior when working with PHAssets. My guess is this is a (purposely) undocumented security/sandboxing restriction.

I was able to work around this problem by copying the underlying file to a user directory, and then performing the operation on the copied file.

I did this in a loop.  Occasionally, the copy fails with a vague file permissions error.  When it does, I retry it after a few seconds (using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`).  Eventually, it works!

Comment: How were you able to make sure it's deleted from Documents folder when done?

Comment: I did this two ways: 1) my use case was uploading video to S3.  I knew when it finished, and could delete the file.  2) As a backup, I persisted a list of the copied files (in NSUserDefaults), and periodically deleted stale files on app launch.  Also, I stored these files in a temp directory (as obtained from `NSFileManager.URLForDirectory(.ItemReplacementDirectory ...)`.  In the worst case, iOS cleans up the files eventually.

Comment: @Gizmodo can you accept the answer if it works for you? Thanks! 

Comment: This answer does a similar/same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167868/129202