# Share live photo using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have implemented the `PHLivePhoto` framework for saving photo's as `PHAsset` objects, which works fine. However, sharing livePhoto's using `UIActivityController` raises the following error:

> Error: resource not available

Below is my code:

```
                PHLivePhoto.request(withResourceFileURLs: [ URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.MOV"), URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.JPG")],
                                placeholderImage: nil,
                                targetSize: videoSize!,
                                contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit,
                                resultHandler: { (livePhoto, info) -> Void in
                                    if let objLivePhoto = livePhoto {
    let objShare = [objLivePhoto]
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController.init(activityItems: objShare, applicationActivities: nil)
                controller.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: {
        })

      }

  })
```

Comment: Sharing PHAssets through UIActivityController seems to cause issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707939/sharing-video-phasset-via-uiactivitycontroller